# Filling column with consecutive numbers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, unique-id

I make a new column in my attribute table and it has a default value (for example 0). I want to (probably using the Field Calculator) have the result that row 1 has the value 1, row 2=2 and so on, just like a numbered index.

How do I do this in the Field Calculator (including the use of `$rownum` which I think I need for switching to the line)?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Just put `$rownum` (QGIS 2) or `@row_number` (QGIS 3) as the expression.

An up-to-date list of all the Field Calculator functions can be read in the [official docs](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#functions-list).

Comment: In QGIS 3.28.9, adding a new field via the Field Calculator adds the column but the numbering looks pretty random. I was hoping to sort an existing "suburb" column alphabetically and then add this field so that suburbs close to A are numbered lower than suburbs close to Z. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 14):

@ArMoraer has developped an interesting plugin to be able to control the way this automatic numbering is made, it's named ["Sort and Number"](https://github.com/ArMoraer/QGISSortAndNumber). You can use it to fill a column with unique numbers by taking into account 3 other fields to sort your data like you want before numbering.

See the source topic : [Is there a way to assign row number for sorted table by column in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192048/is-there-a-way-to-assign-row-number-for-sorted-table-by-column-in-qgis)

Answer (score 11):

If you are using QGIS 3 you must used `@row_number`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For me the best and easiest way is just `$id`, this will return a `id` number to each row indexing it from `0`.

Comment: It returns each feature ID, but the sequence does not necessarily starts at 0 and may have missing values. It is the case after having deleted an existing feature (i.e. start with a layer having 3 features, delete #2, call to $id will return 0 and 2.)

Comment: You are right, if there are missing values, then there will be a problem with the real indexing number. However, I guess that call the `$id`, after deleting rows should corroborate `@row_number`. If I correctly understood your affirmation.

Comment: nope, it will leave holes