# How to select by attributes and calculate aggregates using Modeler?

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I need to know how I can select/aggregate equal attributes in a table.

This is quite the same I want to do. But I want to do it with the modeler.  [How to group and count attribute data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70886/how-to-group-and-count-attribute-data)

The column "Number" has attributes like 1.1 or 1.3 or 4.3. There are a lot of 1.1 or 1.3....in the column. In step1 I want to find all the 1.1 or 1.3 ...for calculating later the weighted average of a value by using the area. The problem is that the "Numbers" are different in all my tables. In EXCEL I could use a data filter to select all the equal attributes. Its not easy to describe...sorry. To say it in one sentence: If „Numbers“ are equal than calculate the weighted average of the Values and create a new table

[image: screenshot_explanation]

But hopefully the screenshot describes the problem better than my words.

Answer (score 1):

For step 1, use `Select features using an expression`.  Open the attribute table by right-clicking on the layer in the TOC.  Look for the button with a curly 'E' on a yellow square.  With the `Select features using an expression` dialog open you can then build an expression by selecting fields, operators, conditionals etc from the function list. You can then use the Basic Statistics tool (in `Vector->Analysis Tools`) on your selection or you can compute the weighted average or use the Statistics by Categories tool (in `Processing->Vector table tools`).  I think this second option will possibly be closest to what you want.

If the statistics are too limited within these tools, you could always save the Attribute data to a CSV (right-click layer and save as).  Then open the csv in Excel, do you calculation and create a table of just the statistics by "Numbers" and then join that table to your data.

Comment: The problem is that I need to now how I can select equal Numbers. Is it the CASE-String I have to use or LIKE/ILIKE?