# QGIS Print composer dynamic labels

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I have created an Atlas. One of my layer contain height restriction for bridges.
I wish to create a label that show the lowest height restriction.

I need to get the height values from my table that are intersecting with the Atlas feature and query for the lowest value to be displayed in the label.
Any ideas how that would be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Generate polygons for atlas pages. You could use a simple grid or [grids for atlas](https://github.com/kiselev-dv/qgis-grids-for-atlas) plugin.
2. Make a query for smaller value of features' attribute covered by polygon.

   Join pages to points, so every point will have a page number, where it appears.
3. Use [Group Stats plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GroupStats/) ([more info here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70886/how-to-group-and-count-attribute-data)): Chose joined page as a classification field for layer with bridges, and you'll find pairs `page - min height`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Maybe I misunderstand you. My atlas pages are generated based on the categories of the roads and and zoom to its extent. So Im not sure how I will go forward to join points to pages. My point data does not share a common attribute with the atlas page.

Comment: In that case, build extent polygons for group of roads, use those polygons as coverage layer in atlas generator. Use a spatial join at stage 2. If you have more than one page for every bridge you need a python script, or process your pages one by one.