# QGIS 3.4 Export data table with a list of all unique variables in a column

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

How can I export a data table which where I have a list of all unique variables contained in one or some attribute columns?

I'm using QGIS 3.4 and I have an attribute column which has about 20 unique characters repeated for 1973 polygons.

I would like to have a list of them and the same for other columns.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?  What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] this question to contain details of the GIS software in use and what steps you have taken to solve the issue. Note that "Is it possible?" questions are invariably answered with, "Yes, " so focusing the question on "How" will provide a  more useful answer.

Comment: Maybe related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70886/how-to-group-and-count-attribute-data and https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/issues/59