# How to select features with same values?

Tags: qgis, select-by-attribute, select, expression

How can I select all those features that has exact same values in their attribute field called "X"?
I think that the solution could be something like the Countif function in Excel, but I haven't found such function in QGIS. I know that there is the Group Stats plugin, but I would like to select values and later work with them.

Comment: What GIS do you mean? In arcmap, it would be Select by Attribut, which is under Selection.

Comment: I mean QGIS (tagged)

Comment: http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/02/tutorial-selecting-multiple-features-in.html

Comment: You want to select all objects with specific value for example 5 or every object which is not unique in column X?

Comment: To give a more detailed sketch: If the field called "X" contains the value '6' three times, value '3' two times, value '7' two times and values '2' , '10', '21' only once, then the seven rows with 6,3 and 7 should be selected.

Comment: Every object without unique values

Comment: Similar issue here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27822/identifying-duplicate-attributes-in-field-using-qgis

Answer (score 3):

Use function **Select features using an expression** ([image] icon in main panel or in attribute table). In expression window type :

`"your_field" = 'value'`

Reacting to your detailing comment:

You can chain your expression with logical operators like: `AND`, `OR` ... so in your example it can be:

`"your_field" = 'value' OR "your_field" = 'value2'`

When you finish writing expression hit *Select* button.

Expression window:

[image]

In this window you can olso browse layer attributes, their values, operators, functions etc.. For more info see [Selecting features in an attribute table](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#selecting-features-in-an-attribute-table) in QGIS documentation.

Comment: I am familiar with these basic selections, but I don't know what is the solution if I have thousands of records and I have no idea that which values have duplicates. @ami shared the link (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27822/identifying-duplicate-attributes-in-field-using-qgis) that describes my problem.

Answer (score 3):

On QGIS 2.16 or later just select your layer and then press f3. You'll get an easy dialog for selecting features by attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Use function Select features using an expression [image: select using expression icon]icon in main panel or in attribute table. In expression window type (replacing field_with_dupes with your field name):

```
count("field_with_dupes", "field_with_dupes") > 1
```