# What means error "Changes to this form will not be saved. 1 field does not meet its constraints."

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, permissionerror

I just updated to QGIS 3.20.
Now I can no longer do multiple updates, due to a constraint at the field ID.
I changed the constraint of ID but the problem stays.

I do can make changes when I select objects in the map.

[image]

[image]

Comment: issue seems to be persistent in QGIS 3.22 ltr as well.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem once. In my case I had placed a constraint on what values a field can contain.

Check the field you're trying to give a new value to, go to the form view of the layer and check if you have placed any constraints on that field. In my case for example it was a "radius" field that I had once decided should not take a value of more than 8. Hope your issue is as simple this one.

[image]

**Edit**
Just realized the field you had issues with was an id field, could be a case of null or duplicates in the id field? Null should be easy to find, for duplicates check this nifty technique:
[Identifying duplicate attributes in field using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27822/identifying-duplicate-attributes-in-field-using-qgis)

Answer (score 2):

Same issue. Had to revert to 3.16.x. Problem gone.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem, on a 3.26.0-Buenos Aires QGIS.

It took me some time to figure it out, but finally, all I had to do was to explicitly add a primary key to the table.

In psql (or any other decent SQL interface to the PostgreSQL server), this did the trick:

```
ALTER TABLE table_that_i_want_to_edit_in_qgis ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
-- (provided that id is actually a SERIAL or something
--  equivalent, a unique identifier for the table 
--  table_that_i_want_to_edit_in_qgis)
```

After that, I was able to edit attributes, modify geometries, etc. in QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

Bug fixed and have to be OK in QGIS 3.26.2.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).