# Why highlighting duplicates does not work in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, query, duplication

I have used the formula from this query [Identifying duplicate attributes in field using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27822/identifying-duplicate-attributes-in-field-using-qgis):

```
  count(1, "FieldWithDuplicates") > 1
```

but it doesn't work in my case, just highlights each value from the column.

What is wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Can you share you data? What if you try this `count(1,  trim("STRUCTURE_NAMECompany")) > 1`?

Comment: It may be related to the conditional formatting, make sure the **`condition`** is the full expression `count(1,"FieldWithDuplicates") > 1`

Comment: @Taras this formula throws 0 in the result and is very slow with execution.

Answer (score 1):

Use Conditional Formatting (1st screenshot) or Select by expression (2nd screenshot) with this expression (replace `value` twice by the name of the field where you want to find duplicates).

```
count (value, group_by:=value) > 1
```

*Conditional formatting*
[image]

*Select by expression*
[image]