# Finding features in QGIS with partly different attributes

Tags: qgis, layers, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I have several layers and they all have identical table organization. I need to find if there are any features that have a different names but the same UUID. I know that this could be done if I connect QGIS with Postgres but is there any way to do this in QGIS only.

Comment: What are you expectations regarding the output ? By *”names”* do you mean an attribute with names ?

Comment: Can you add an example of what you want to find?

Comment: look at `virtual layers`, you can run SQL queries against layer(s)

Answer (score 1):

I would merge the layers first, then with field calculator I would create a a virtual field `"uuid"||'_'||"name"` then using this solution to find duplicates: [Identifying duplicate attributes in field using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27822/identifying-duplicate-attributes-in-field-using-qgis) and then invert selection.