# Automatic numbering of rows in attribute table - QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

In my attribute table, I have districts and cities for Finland as shown in the picture below. Is there a way I can give a number to each city without doing it manually?

[image]

Comment: Could it help? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27739/filling-column-with-consecutive-numbers-in-qgis

Comment: @Vale many thanks for your input, I should have searched more efficiently before posting my question.

Comment: Just a tip, in QGIS3 the function is not `$rownum`, but rather  `@row_number`

Comment: It worked well from row 1 to row 129, and then row the numbering changed to 789 for no reason...