# Adding unique ID automatically in Field calculator as counter in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, fields-attributes, unique-id

[image: uniq]

I tried a lot by Field Calculator but it gives me `NULL` as you show in table and another try it gives me value 1 in all rows.

Most of examples, on internet they are explaining old version and I have QGIS 3 and I am not sure how can I add id for all rows .

If I want to generate random id, how can I do it also.

I did as suggested in answer `$id`

[image]

But could i ask why the values are not  looks like counter, it looks random. If i need to increase by one, how can i do that?

Comment: Update the field with `$id`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filling column with consecutive numbers in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27739/filling-column-with-consecutive-numbers-in-qgis)

Comment: You should try to order your "q" column to check if the randomness-like view is not caused by another column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest answer is the `$id` variable.

Be careful though, it doesn't auto-increment after your first field calculation.

- See here related infos : [Is there a way of auto_increment for the ID column in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132346/is-there-a-way-of-auto-increment-for-the-id-column-in-qgis)

Answer (score 7):

The easiest and preferred way is to use the processing algorithm "Add Autoincremental Field"

Comment: where can i fnd it ,i looked for it but i did not know,where is it located

Comment: Processing -> Toolbox and search for it.