# QGIS @row_number with defined intervals

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I would like to write a sequence of numbers of lines that goes from 1 to 90 and restart on 1 again.

For example

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

Comment: First of all, your problem is not very clear. You probably need to provide some code example or a screenshot for what you are doing and where you get stuck. It may be better to let others know what you have already tried before you asked it here. What I have understood from this incomplete description is that you want to add a new field filled with row numbers,  see [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27739/filling-column-with-consecutive-numbers-in-qgis). To sort based on another feature use [Sort and Number plugin](https://github.com/ArMoraer/QGISSortAndNumber).

Comment: no, i would just like to create a new column where the numbers of lines created go from 1 to 90 and then start from 1 to 90 again

Answer (score 7):

You may use this expression in your field calculator.

```
if(  @row_number  % 90=0,90,@row_number  % 90)
```