# Using QGIS field calculator to create an 'fid' column according to a value from another column

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, expression, excel

I have a shapefile with 1,800 rows. I need to edit this file as follow:

- Row_name is from 1 to 45
- Col is from 1 to 39
- fid should be from 1 to 1800 in order (This is the new field I need to create).

I tried using $id from 'Record and Attributes', but for some reason it starts with fid 1 at row_5 instead of row_1.

How can I use the field calculator in QGIS to do so? I wish it were like Excel where I can just copy and paste or use the corner dropdown tool. Can you write a QGIS expression to be used in the field calculator?

Example:

```
Row_name    Col     fid
row_1       1       1
row_1       2       2
row_1       3       3
row_1       4       4
...
row_1       39      39
row_2       1       40
...
row_2       5       44
...
row_3       1       79
row_3       2       80
row_3       3       81
...
```

I tried using @row_number, but the same problem happens. The value should be dependent on row_#. This question is not the same as [Filling column with consecutive numbers in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27739/filling-column-with-consecutive-numbers-in-qgis)
[image]

The Sort and Number plugin also does it incorrectly:
[image]

Comment: @Taras I checked it, but it is not the same since the numbers do not need to start counting from 1 again.

Comment: @geozelot would you please review my comments below?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hacky solution using the field calculator:

```
array_find(
  array_agg(
    expression := to_int(substr("Row name", 5))*10*maximum("Col")+"Col",
    order_by   := to_int(substr("Row name", 5))*10*maximum("Col")+"Col"
  ),
  to_int(substr(attributes()['Row name'], 5))*10*maximum(attributes()['Col'])+attributes()['Col']
) + 1
```

---

Probably the most sane solution:

- drop column `fid`
- within the *DB Manager* navigate to `Virtual Layers | Project layers`
- run

  ```
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTR("Row name", 5) AS INT), CAST("Col" AS INT)) AS fid, *
  FROM   <your_layer_name>
  ;
  ```
- create new *Virtual Layer* from the result
- *Save as...* your preferred file type

Comment: Using DB Manager I get the error: Query preparation error on PRAGMA table_info(_tview): no such column: id2

Comment: Using Field Calculator I get the error: Eval Error: Could not calculate aggregate for: to_int(substr("id1", 5, NULL)) * 10 * maximum("id2", NULL, NULL) + "id2" (Field 'id2' not found)

Comment: @JoseLuisLandivarS Ya,  of course you'll have to replace those with your actual column names...

Comment: @JoseLuisLandivarS ...and to make that clear, the `5` in both versions of the `substr[ing]` functions needs to match the position of the first number within the string in your `"Row name"` values.

Comment: I tried using "SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SUBSTR(Col, 8), Row) AS fid, * FROM   '2022_da_wheat_irr_boundary';", but row-10 Col 1 gets 40. 40 should be row-2 Col 1. Any suggestions?

Comment: @JoseLuisLandivarS Yes, it needs a `CAST` to `INTEGER` - I updated the query.