# Field Calculator: @row_number adds the Feature ID + 1 instead of the row-number

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression, vector-grid, numbering

I created a grid of hexagons and kept only the hexagons in a circle. In effect many hexagon-ids are missing and the remaining ones start at 1409.

[image]

I want them to be numbered consecutively in a logic way starting with 1 (top to bottom, left to right); i. e. 1409 should be 1, 1410 should be 2 ... 1495 should be 9, 1496 should be 10 ...

The attempt to use the expression `@row_number` in the field calculator as suggested by this post: [Filling column with consecutive numbers in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27739/filling-column-with-consecutive-numbers-in-qgis) used the Feature ID + 1 for the new value, as can be seen in the column 'test'.

[image]

From the list of functions (https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#functions-list) I understand that it should take the row-number instead, which would result in the exact sequence I desire.

Comment: Not an answer but there is a sort and number plugin which you could use instead.

Comment: After deleting the features, did you toggle edit mode to save the changes? If not, no wonder `@row_number` returns the same value

Comment: @John Thank you very much, I use the "sort and number"-plugin as a workaraound. Still not the neatest solution, but it does the job.

Comment: Babel: I exported the selected hexagons as a seperate shape-file, so saving should not be a problem, I also closed and reopened QGIS many times. Also the row-numbers started with 1, so it is not that the original rows have been used, as the original hexagon 1 has been deleted. Instead I received a consecutive series of numbers 1 to 5966, just as I wanted, only their placing was weird with 1 somewhere in the middle at the bottom. At the original grid, the 1 was in the upper left corner, which I cut off.
With a rectangular grid as the original one, the expression `@row_number` works fine btw.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behivour you describe, when using @row_number, I get an increasing no. starting with 1, see screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFFNp.jpg
 Can you provide/share the exported shapefile?

Comment: @Babel When I recreated a file for you, I had the decisive idea. It seems to work just fine when I save the original grid as a shape-file. When I use it as a temporary scratch-layer and afterwards save only the hexagons selected by my circle as a shape-file, it produces the errors I described.

Maybe a beginner's mistake. But it is good to know this for the future. Thank you anyways for your efforts!

Comment: @SAM You should add what solved your problem as an answer and then accept it, so that other people can find it.

Comment: I deleted your edit, as it is the same as the answer. Due to the policy of this site, mark your answer as accepted (hit the checkmark) to signalize to other users that this answer solved your problem. See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Babel I will do this, but as it is my own answer I have to wait 2 days to be able to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to work just fine, if I save every step as a shape-file. Originally I always used the original grid as a temporary scratch layer and saved only the selected hexagons which form a circle. This created the error. So just make sure to save every step as a shape-file, it is worth the effort. Many thanks to Babel https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/88814/babel for forcing me to rethink the process.